Example of a covering space of a manifold that is not paracompact
Let $M$ be a topological manifold. This means that $M$ is a paracompact, Hausdorff topological space that is also locally Euclidean. It is common in textbooks on manifolds (such as Lee's comprehensive books) that a proof is given saying that a covering space $\tilde{M}$ of $M$ will also be Hausdorff and locally Euclidean. Moreover, if $M$ had extra structure such as smoothness, then $\tilde{M}$ can also be given the same structure so that the covering projection will be smooth, etc. If one takes the common definition that manifolds are second-countable (instead of the weaker condition of paracompactness), then $\tilde{M}$ will be second-countable and therefore a manifold with respect to that definition.
I'm wondering if the same applies if $M$ is just assumed to be paracompact. That is, if $\tilde{M}$ is paracompact assuming that $M$ is paracompact. I know that a locally Euclidean Hausdorff space is second-countable if and only if it has countably many connected components and is paracompact, and that the long line is the usual example of a locally Euclidean Hausdorff space that is not paracompact (and hence not second-countable). So it seems that if one were to look for a counter-example, we would need a covering space that has uncountably many connected components. Another avenue is to find a topological manifold $M$ which has the long line as a covering space. Do such examples exist?

It is not true that $\tilde{M}$ will be second-countable if $M$ is second-countable. A trivial counter-example is the projection $M\times X\rightarrow M$, where $X$ is some uncountable discrete set. The actual fact is that if $M$ is a connected manifold [note that second-countable and paracompact are equivalent for a connected, locally Euclidean, Hausdorff space, so this is unambiguous] and $\tilde{M}$ is a connected covering space of $M$, then it is second-countable again (and thus again a connected manifold). Now, if $M$ is a paracompact, locally Euclidean, Hausdorff space  and $\tilde{M}$ a covering space of $M$, then every component of $\tilde{M}$ is a connected covering space of some component of $M$, hence a connected manifold and, in particular, paracompact. Thus, $\tilde{M}$ is a disjoint union of paracompact spaces, hence itself paracompact.

The definition of covering maps that I use in my books includes the assumption that the covering space is path-connected. So under that definition, it is true that every covering space of a manifold is second-countable.

@JackLee Ah right, I forgot about the convention. In that case, the statement is true of course. In this case, any covering space is actually a covering space of a component of the base already, so the generalization is immediate all the same.
